# geodjango / olwidget: adding a control to a map

Tags: openlayers, geodjango, olwidget

I want to add an extra control to an OpenLayers map generated by olwidget to handle clicks like in this example:
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/click.html

```
<script>
    OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {
        ... click handling code goes here ...
    });

    var click = new OpenLayers.Control.Click();
    map.addControl(click);
    click.activate();
</script>
```

But the javascript generated by the olwidget does not assign the created map to a variable so I can hook it:

```
new olwidget.Map("id_coords", [...], {...});
```

If only it was like:

```
var map = new olwidget.Map("id_coords", [...], {...});
```

The above code would run.

What is the best approach in this case? Should I manipulate the olwidget template that generates the map script or is there a more natural way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a recent update to [olwidget](https://github.com/yourcelf/olwidget), it is now possible to define individual templates for rendering posts in the Meta class definition:

```
class PostForm(MapModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        template = 'posts/post_map.html'
```

So, defining a custom template and assigning the map to a javascript variable seems to be the right approach.